# Size of an ActiveRecord_Relation object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I have the following query:

```
User.joins(:posts).group('users.id').having('count(user_id) > 1')
```

The returned class is `User::ActiveRecord_Relation`.

If I call `.size` on it, it returns a hash. If I call `.size.size` I get the correct size returned.

Is this really how I should get the size of an ActiveRecord_Relation, or how is the correct way otherwise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You called `group` method, that's why hash is returned for the first `.size` call.
Let's say you have following hash when calling `size` first time:

```
hash = {106=>1, 171=>1, 79=>1, 66=>1, 160=>3, 73=>1, 182=>1, 165=>1, 97=>7, 116=>1}
```

Then you need to sum all values from that hash:

```
hash.values.reduce(:+)
=> 18
```

Comment: Would you say that `.size.size` is the way to go if I want to know how many pairs the returning hash contains?

Answer (score 6):

It's important to understand why you get a hash when you call `#size` here.

`#size` will execute a `SELECT COUNT(*)` query if the association is not loaded yet. This is equivalent to calling `#count`. So you get a hash.

But if somehow the association has already been loaded into memory, `#size` won't execute any additional query, but will get the length of the association. In this case, the length of the hash. Try the following in console:

```
query = User.joins(:posts).group('users.id').having('count(user_id) > 1'); #don't load the association 
query.size   # => hash
query.size   # => length of the previous hash
```

So it's not a good idea to rely on chaining `#size` here unless you're sure the association wouldn't have been loaded before this. Instead, use `#length` for this:

```
User.joins(:posts).group('users.id').having('count(user_id) > 1').length  # => integer
```

`#length` doesn't execute the additional query, and will always load the whole association into memory so it's a bit slower and is hungrier. But in practice it's usually not an issue unless you're loading a huge amount of records.

By the way, if all you want is to find number of users with more than one post, there's no need for `#join`:

```
Post.group('user_id').having('count(user_id) > 1').length
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation. Two things though, calling `query.size` twice didn't change the output and your suggestion on the last line didn't work out for me. "ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "posts.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function"

Comment: For the example in console, you need to make sure `query` isn't loaded before you call the first `#size` (don't forget the semicolon at the end of the first line to suppress rails from loading it and make sure it's not loaded before).

The last code works in MySQL. for PostgreSQL, you might want to use `Post.select(:id, :user_id).group('user_id').having('count(user_id) > 1').length`